# collectionView is not showing in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, swift5

I want to show a UICollectionView in a UITableViewController class. I have seen videos and codes of that working, but apparently it is not working in Swift 5 anymore or at least I don't know how to set it up in Swift 5. I do everything programmatically. This is the function I am calling in my viewDidLoad() but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
func configureCollectionView() {
    
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical

    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height)! - (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!)

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.register(SearchCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SearchCell")

    tableView.addSubview(collectionView)
    tableView.separatorColor = .clear

}
```

I am also calling these collectionView functions:

```
minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt

minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt

sizeForItemAt

numberOfItemsInSection

cellForItemAt

didSelectItemAt
```

What can I do to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

set it up like this
`collectionView.backgroundColor = .black`, can you see the `black` background?

Comment: I cannot .. I tried calling it in my  configureCollectionView() func and also in viewDidLoad(). I also tried tableView.isHidden = true. That only made the screen go black, to check and see if I now see the collectionView, I set the collectionView.backgroundColor = .red, still didn't show. So apparently I am not calling the collectionView at the right place?

Comment: I am using a searchBar. I want the tableView to appear when I use the searchBar, and if I don't use it, I want the collectionView to appear.

Comment: Is the size of ```layout ``` set?

Comment: `let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical


let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height)! - (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!)`

Comment: @swiftcrackhead1 I think for your requirement you can use a UIViewcontroller with a table and a collectionview. That will be a simple solution.

Comment: How and where do I do that? @AkilanCB

Comment: @swiftcrackhead1 Just create a UIViewController, add a collectionView and a tableView as its subviews. Hide and unhide as desired